# search engine friendly blog urls

Tags: php, mysql

Hey i am in the process of making a blog for my site, i have decided to make my own rather than use a 3rd party, however i cannot figure out how to make the url's seo friendly atm they are like this /blogpost.php?id=15 however i want it to be /the-title is there any way to do this without htaccess? atm i am using this to make the urls'

```
echo '<a href="blogpost.php?id='.$row['id'].'">';
```

Then i am using _GET to get the id and then get the information from the database, i could replace id with name but that gives me /blogpost.php?title=The-Title

Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern

Comment: Thanks for the link, i'll need to look into front controller patterns cheers

Answer (score 1):

In your htaccess you put something like this (if using apache)

```
RewriteEngine On

#ignores real files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#ignores real directorys
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#ignores symlinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

#forwards the request onto index.php with the orignal querystring still intact

RewriteRule (.+) index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
```

Then any thing after the / will be forwared to the $_GET['url'] in index.php.
Then in index.php you can have a bootstrap class that will `explode` this by /.
Then you can load the appropriate class based on the first element in this array.

For example if the url was /articles

it would load the articles controller based on the /articles

Or if the url was /articles/about-something

The articles controller will load the article by fetching an article from the database with the about-something slug.

Comment: Cheers for this, i will attempt it and let you know the results seams like i have allot of code to edit to get this to work, worth a shot, cheers.